# UIButton: change titleColor when click and change back when otherButton Clicked

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want the aButton change the titleColor from WHITE to RED when I click

But when I click other button,I want aButton change back to WHITE

How can I do that?

Here is the code I write,But It not work as I want.

```
[aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setSelected:` to change the selection state of button.

in viewDidLoad:

```
[aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

[bButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

aButton.selected = YES;


- (IBAction)aButton_or_bButtonClicked:(id)sender {

    if(aButton.selected) {
        aButton.selected = NO;
        bButton.selected = YES;
    }
    else {
        aButton.selected = YES;
        bButton.selected = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Should work like this:

```
- (IBAction)aButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (IBAction)bButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```